# Adding a search function to return a social security number

Tags: c++

I have a program that takes in user input.  Once the user information is on file a .dat file  stores it.  The admin should be able to search on the user social and retrieve the social on file by searching by the social..  I was thinking of using a switch statement where they can search by social, last name, and birthdate.

I had something like this but might be wrong.

```
void Database:: SearchSocial(int n)
{
string searChedSoc;
char social;
ifstream socialS;
char *myfile = "database.txt";
ifstream socialS ( "database.txt", std::ios::in);
// exit if unable to open file.
if (!socialS.is_open())
{
cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
exit(1);
}

cout << "Enter Scoial: ";
cin >> social;

        searChedSoc = chrFileName.SearchSocial(social);
        cout << "The social is on file: " << searChedSoc << endl;
        if(social != NULL) 
            cout << "This is not the correct social " << posNum->SearchSocial() << endl;
        else (social == searChedSoc)
            cout << "The searched number is:" << searChedNum << endl;
        system("pause");
        system("cls");*/
```

How do you put together something like this? Is there an example or am I approaching this correctly?

Comment: wait... why do you have all these people's social security number?

Comment: relax folks - it is likely homework

Comment: Yeah it is a study assignment.  I thought I was going the right direction but seems off...

Comment: I figure out I was doing wrong..  LOL  Thanks for any consideration though..

Comment: Hi Mikey, you should post your solution here as an answer (you can answer your own questions). Just incase it helps anyone.

Comment: oh okay thanks! I did not even think of that I will add it.. I get points for it too right..  Yeah I was on a time crunch and in panic mode because at work and could not find a real good example,,,when I gave up and stopped panic I started reading and came across the answer...

Comment: Plus I decided to use SQLexpress on versus a file but not complete..

Comment: is it still relevant? can you post your answer as well?